# Prime number generator - python

Tags: python, primes

It seems the program just keeps iterating over the same numbers.

```
x = input("Enter a number: ")
for p in range(2,int(x)+1):
    for i in range(2,p):
        if p%i == 0:
            pass
        else:
            print (p)

print ("Done")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = input("Enter a number: ")
for p in range(2,int(x)+1):
    for i in range(2,p):
        if p%i == 0:
            break    # <== break here (when a factor is found)
    else:            # <==else belongs to the for, not the if
        print (p)

print ("Done")
```

Also explained [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing
>   for or while loop.
>
> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop
>   terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the
>   condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is
>   terminated by a break statement. This is exemplified by the following
>   loop, which searches for prime numbers:

Comment: What about change `p` to sqrt of p, so it will prevent from checking all the way to p. `for i in range(2, int(p*0.5)):`

Comment: @yopy, that's an obvious optimisation, but distracts from the actual question here

Comment: ah sorry, i thought he was looking for primality.

Comment: @yopy It is funny that people always point out ways how to optimize trial division primality tests. If you need a performant primality test you would never go with trial division in the first place.